# How to insert and simulate large amount of data into Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, iotdb

How to quickly insert time series data in large batches to Apache IoTDB? Also I want know how to simulate large batches of time series data? Does IoTDB itself includes any ways to simulate data without connecting to other software?

Answer (score 0):

There are interfaces of writing data in large amount in Apache IoTDB, `insertTablet` and `insertRecords`. For simulating batch data, you can search for `SessionExample` in IoTDB document in github or directly use `benchmark` tool in IoTDB.